# Tensorflow unique on batches

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I would like to find the size of a set of integers (no repetitions) for many sets. Currently
I use

```
...
un_3 = tf.unique(dataset_iter.get_next())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
       result = sess.run(un_3, feed_dict={Y: some_other_data})
       ...save result..
```

to achieve that. But this works only on 1D tensors. I have two questions:

1) Will moving to batches (matrices) of say 100 vectors run the code on parallel on the GPU thus save performance?

2) If so then how to use a batch-supported version of tf.unique()?

- Can I use *map_fn* somehow to run *unique()* on parallel?

3) If not then how to make sure the above code runs efficiently on a GPU?

--------- Edit -----

I was able to run *tf.unique()* using

```
@tf.contrib.eager.defun
def func(tensors):
    y, idx = tf.unique(tensors) #, dtype=tf.int32)
    return tf.size(y)

un_3 = tf.map_fn(func, un_2, infer_shape=False)
```

But the question remains - will it run parallel on the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

The map_fn version is not parallel. Hence I used the following (not so clean) code to handle batches:

```
un_3_00, _ = tf.unique(un_2[0,:])
un_3_01, _ = tf.unique(un_2[1,:])
un_3_02, _ = tf.unique(un_2[2,:])
...
```